# Hide Children of Node

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot-4

I am making a addon for my friends, and I am trying to make a custom node. It works, but I have a problem, the children of the custom node is visible in the scene dock.

[image: Nodes Screenshot]

The `Text` node has children, but they aren't visible in the scene dock. I want the same thing with the Inventory node. (I added the `Text`, `GridContainer`,and `CenterContainer` nodes from another scene through code)

How would I go about this. (Preferably a solutions that uses GDScript)

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean visible/hidden in the Scene dock list of the active scene's nodes (in the editor UI) or do you mean visible in the rendered scene (the game)?

Comment: Hidden in the Scene dock. I will update the question to include this information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are adding nodes from code in a tool script, you need to set their `owner` in order for them to show in the scene dock and for them to be saved alongside the scene. For example, like this:

```
add_child(t)
t.owner = self if owner == null else owner
```

Since you don't want that, you just **don't set their `owner` property** (i.e. remove that part of the code).

Bear in mind this means that your custom node must also add its children in runtime since they won't be part of the scene.

*You can use `Engine.is_editor_hint()` to check if your code is running in the editor... But since you want to do the same thing in runtime, you don't need to do that either.*

Be aware that since they won't be accesible from the scene dock, the users of your addon won't be able to modify their properties directly or connect signals to or from them directly.

Comment: OH THANK YOU! This worked! Thank you @Theraot! Helpful as always!